Outside air flexed in the into the cold air return
We have fresh air through an outside vent feeding the cold air return. In the summer we get warm air in the house and cold in the winter. Do we need this?

Generally, humans need air to stay alive, so yes.   If you are asking about a feature of your HVAC system, we will need much more information, such a make and model of the system as well as type of home you have and where you live on the planet.

To be clear, are you talking about conditioned air circulation or the combustion circuit? Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise to add detail about your system.

are you certain that it is feeding the cold air return? ... it may be feeding the burner

if you use gas in your home than fresh air is a must have

Usually outside air for in the house(not the heater/burner) is supplied though some type of heat exchanger as a separate unit to the HVAC system.

Do you have a lot of air being pumped out of the house by a hood over the cooking stove, out the clothes dryer, out bathroom vent fans? Do you have a gas stove?

If it's there, someone, at some point, thought they needed it. This isn't something that's normally done when installing a HVAC unit unless reuired by local codes. I've had people request it when they've gone crazy with installing "airtight" windows and doors. The outside vent allows for new air to get into the house... but if there isn't another vent for old air to escape, it doesn't do much good. Most homes have enough airflow through normal usage of windows, doors and existing vents. Your vent should have a damper on it so you can open and close it as you deem necessary

Probably depends on local code. In Washington state it's required.

Mark but does the Washingoton state code specify that it is to be fitted with an energy recovery system? AFIK these exchange heat between outgoing an incoming air streams.

@JimStewart - No, but it's just an air intake. There's no air exhaust to exchange heat with.  Presumably the stale air leaves through leakage paths, open doors and windows, and exhaust fans.  My understanding is that it's to ensure there is some specified rate of fresh air brought in - low enough to not be a huge energy loss, but high enough to prevent excessive CO2 and water vapor buildup.
